# Create files and directories with japanese path and POCO c++

Tags: c++, utf-8, poco, utf-16

How I can manage file system from POCO C++ in japanese version of Win? I mean, I working with japanese characters, and my application can't create any file in filesystem using:

```
Poco::UnicodeConverter::convert(std::wstring,std::string)
```

With resultant std::string I can't do any operation in filesystem using:

```
Poco::File file(std::string);
```

Is a problem about UTF8/UTF16? Any idea?

Comment: Check out the "Config.h" header content, does it have `POCO_WIN32_UTF8` defined?

Comment: @didierc Yes, it is.

Comment: Did you build the library by yourself?

Comment: @didierc yes, with make poco-master

Comment: Well, I guess I won't be able to help you much beyond that. Did you try asking at http://ja.stackoverflow.com ? (you need to speak Japanese).